# How to add Json in Var using an array

Tags: c#

I am trying to add below JSON in VAR as an array.

```
[
    {
        "path": "test",
        "op" : "replace",
        "from" : "null",
        "value" :"7c45f39c-708b-4d54-8fff-421640dyuuii"
    } 
]
```

I tried the code below and it didn't work me.

```
var data = new
        {
         path="test",
         op ="replace",
         from = "null",
         value ="7c45f39c-708b-4d54-8fff-421640dyuuii"
        };
```

How can declare this as an array?

Comment: with `VAR` you seem to be refering to anonymous types | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `new { ... }` declares an object.  You can use `new[] { }` to declare an array.  And then *within* that declaration you can declare you object(s).  For example:

```
var data = new[] {
    new {
       path = "test",
       op = "replace",
       from = "null",
       value = "7c45f39c-708b-4d54-8fff-421640dyuuii"
    }
};
```

---

As an aside... Note that with implicit types you *can't* declare an empty array, such as:

```
var data = new[] { };
```

As the compiler would need an example of the object to infer the type.  In the example above the compiler infers an anonymous type from the inner `new { ... }` declaration of your object.  Any type would work, there just needs to be one.  Otherwise you'd need to explicitly define a type.  For example:

```
var data = new string[] {};
```